# Automatic Android Click/Tap tracking

Tags: android, analytics

Is there a clever way to "do something" every time a user clicks or taps on the screen?  I'd like to know which view they tapped on, and do it without having to replace all my standard views with custom views.

Basically, I want to add click tracking in my app to help with analytics.  We already have page tracking (by using a shared superclass for every activity), but in some cases page tracking isn't enough and we actually want to track clicks.

How can I execute a function every time the user clicks on a View on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

In each of your Activities, just add this at the end of `onCreate` (this is especially easy if all your Activities are subclasses of a custom Activity, because then you only need to write this once):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        //handle your code here
        return false;//don't absorb the touch.
    }
});
```

**Edit**

The above code does not allow easy recognition of which `View`s are touched. The below code will. Note that this may break other `onTouchListener`s if the `View` in question already has registered an `onTouch` event. If not, this will work great. It uses my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library to select all views in the hierarchy and set uses code like above to handle touches without absorbing the event. The best place for this would be at the end of `onCreate`, in every `Activity`:

First, select the highest level of the architecture you want. If your layout's root view has an id, that would be the best thing:

```
$.with(this, R.id.root_id)
```

If not, either add one, or select the topmost view (above your layout). Note that for analytics this may provide some results you do not need:

```
$.with(this).selectAll()
```

Now, on the end of this selection, append the following:

```
.each(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ d, Object... args) {
        d.view(0).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                //do something with the clicked view, such as:
                handleTouch(v, e);
                return false;//don't absorb the touch.
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Then have a new method:

```
private void handleTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    //handle the view touch.
}
```

Comment: Will this tell me which view was clicked, or will `v` always be the content view?  eg. If my activity has a listview with a bunch of view items, will it tell me which item was clicked?

Comment: @emmby No, this will not give you which view has been clicked, but you can get the location on screen where they clicked, and can determine which views lay underneath your finger. Can you please clarify this in your question if that is a requirement?

Comment: @emmby I made an edit to help determine which views are selected

Comment: the update is clever, but breaking existing onTouchListeners is probably a deal breaker

Comment: @emmby, It sounds like you will need to create custom classes to do what you are trying to do. There may be some options outside of that, such as code injection (such as adding a method at pre-compile time to the `View` class, that handles touches for all views).